# How can I find who called when my phone was off in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to know who called when my phone was switched off.

Is there any predefined class available in android to find this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

When the phone is switched off, it cannot receive calls or record call attempts.

Your network operator knows when somebody is calling you and your phone is not in a network, but that data is generally not available.